# El Capitan Terminal.app keeps showing overlay

Tags: terminal, macos, tmux

New terminal in El Capitan keeps showing this annoying overlay with tmux commands describing my current tmux session. How do I turn it off?
[image: overlay in terminal.app]

Comment: Are you hovering over the title bar?

Comment: nope, I could just be staring at vim and it'll appear